# Bot Sends Multiple Times The Content Of The Message | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, message, helper

I am trying to make a dark net bot for a roleplay discord server (FiveM), but when i send a message at the specific channel it send the message back multiple times

```
bot.on('message', message=>{
    
    if(message.channel.id == "ID") {
        if(isNaN(message.content)) {
            message.channel.send(message.content)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please don't edit posts to replace the content just because your problem is solved. [so] is working to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

Comment: Please don't edit questions into something useless, because of the reasons that @GalaxyCat105 mentioned. I've rolled back all of your edits of this kind. If you want to delete a question, you can do it using the delete button, but you should do so with a good reason (especially if it has answers - or even good answers!). Deletion will also be undone if found inappropriate. Please read [this Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your bot is registering it's own message and, because it's the same as it's supposed to react on, it responds with the message content which in turn is the same as it's supposed to react on and so on and so on...

The good news is that you can fix this with a simple line of code.

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

Put that above your `if(message.channel.id == "ID")` and all will be fine. It checks if the author of a message is a bot and if so returns, meaning it doesn't execute the rest of the code.